# Javascript: Can't pull the .text() from an html tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm editing this to add my solution based on georg's answer. The solution is at the bottom.

I am trying to get the enclosed text from a given tag using.

```
var substring = txt.find(tag).eq(i).text();
```

**Sample Data:**

The variable *tag* holds "h1".

The variable *txt* holds "<p>one.</p><h1>fish</h1><p>two fish. red fish. blue fish.</p>".

**The Expectation:**

*subString* == "fish"

**The Result:**

*subString* == null

**Code:**

```
this.mpactIdeation_getTagContentsKeyphrase = function( tag, kp ) {
    try {
        var result = 0;
        var num = 0;
        var txt = this.oText;

        var tagcount = this._mpactIdeation_countOccurrences( txt, tag, false );

        txt = jQuery(txt);

        for (i = 0; i < tagcount; i++) {
            tag = this._mpactIdeation_tagToText(tag);
            var substring = txt.find(tag).eq(i).text();
            result += this._mpactIdeation_countOccurrences(substring, kp, false);
        }

        return result;
    }  catch(e) {
        console.log(e);
        return false;
    }
}
```

**Solution:**

```
    this.mpactIdeation_getTagContentsKeyphrase = function( tag, kp ) {
        try {
            var result = 0;
            var num = 0;
            var txt = this.oText;

            var tagcount = this._mpactIdeation_countOccurrences( txt, tag, false );

            for (i = 0; i < tagcount; i++) {
                tag = this._mpactIdeation_tagToText(tag);
                var substring = jQuery('<div>').html(txt).find(tag).eq(i).text();
                result += this._mpactIdeation_countOccurrences(substring, kp, false);
            }

            return result;
        }  catch(e) {
            console.log(e);
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Comment: `.text()` is applicable on a JQuery object, not a string variable.

Comment: @AhsN Doesn't txt = jQuery(txt); turn it into a true html object string?

Comment: what is the value of tag that you are testing?

Comment: No, it will return you an array of the elements, which is not easily filtered if the structure of the string is not consistent. I'll provide you with a simpler way to do that as answer

Comment: @AshkanMobayenKhiabani, I'm not sure what you are asking if it isn't in the section of my question titled "Sample Data". The var tag == "h1", txt == "<p>one.</p><h1>fish</h1><p>two fish. red fish. blue fish.</p>", the target substring is <h1>fish</h1>. So I would expect that var substring = txt.find(tag).eq(i).text(); would yield subString = "fish".

Comment: @AhsN thanks I'd appreciate that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use `find` you have to put your html in a container:

```js
txt = "<p>one.</p><h1>fish</h1><p>two fish. red fish. blue fish.</p>";

result = $('<div>').html(txt).find('h1').text()

alert(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks! Works great. I'm using jQuery in no conflicts mode so its jQuery() instead of $(). I will edit my question to include my solution based on your input.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I would do it:

```
var tag="h1"
var txt = "<p>one.</p><h1>fish</h1><p>two fish. red fish. blue fish.</p>";


var result = txt.match(new RegExp("<"+tag+">(.*)</"+tag+">"));
console.log(result[1]);

alert(result[1]);
```

[Here is the **JSFiddle** demo](https://jsfiddle.net/anoorally/wLdn827t/)

The string was filtered using the tag u provided via regex and the text between the tags are shown as a message.

Comment: this is a very bad idea. imaging this: `<tag><tag>some value</tag> some other value</tag>`

Comment: That method doesn't allow me to iterate through multiple tags of the same type though. I'm trying to iterate through all of a given tag (note the function arguments) then count up how many times a given string (var kp) is enclosed within all occurrences of the given tag.

Comment: @AshkanMobayenKhiabani The `tag` is a defined variable, which is this case has been specified as 'h1' so only `<h1>` tags are filtered.

Comment: @mpactMEDIA You can always loop over the result variable with index greater than 1 and tweak teh regex to find more than just one tag, and u can do further string manipulation to check the content and count

Comment: yeah i know, and I just wanted to show the case that regular expressions would fail

Answer (score 0):

I have tried doing in a similar fashion and was able to do it quite well.

Please refer [**demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/xdcdreow/).

Code below:

HTML:

```
 <div class="test">Test div 1</div>
 <div class="test">Test div 2</div>
 <div class="test">Test div 3</div>


<div class="newDiv"><p>New Div</p></div>
```

JS:

```
     $(function(){
          var len = document.getElementsByClassName('test').length;
          for(var i = 0; i<len;i++){
          var test = $('.test').eq(i).text();

          $('.newDiv').append('<br>Loop ' + (i+1) + ' text = ' + test);
          }
      });
```